# How to center material ui card? (react)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I've been trying so many things to figure out how to center a material ui card in react. Please help me! Thanks :)

[website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Uef.png)

```
<Grid container justify="center">
                        <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345}} display="flex" alignItems="center"justifyContent="center">
                        
                        <CardMedia
                               
                                      component="img"
                                      height="140"
                                      image="astroline-white_betterq.png"
                                      alt="astroline banner"
                        />
                        
                        <CardContent>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                        
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                        Astroline is a space / scifi game about a apocalyptic disaster that happened on Earth.
                        </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions>
                        <Button size="small" elevation="1" onClick={() => navigate("/astroline")}>Learn More
                        </Button>

                        </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to flex the parent.
Add the following to the parent element:

```css
.parent-element-class {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Alternatively, you can assign a class to the MUI card and do the usual

```css
.mui-card-root-class-name {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

div centering approach.
How exactly to do this depends on how you use MUI so share some code.

You can use Wrappers such as:

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/
or
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/

Mui's documentation is actually really good.

EDIT:
Try adding `width: 100%` to the parent, it should center it then.

Answer (score -1):

In your `Grid` content element add this

`<Grid container justifyContent="center" >`

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-swanson-e1dlrf?file=/demo.tsx)

```
<Grid container justifyContent="center" >
  <Card
    sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}
    display="flex"
    alignItems="center"
    justifyContent="center"
  >
    <CardMedia
      component="img"
      height="140"
      image="astroline-white_betterq.png"
      alt="astroline banner"
    />

    <CardContent>
      <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div"></Typography>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
        Astroline is a space / scifi game about a apocalyptic disaster that
        happened on Earth.
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
    <CardActions>
      <Button
        size="small"
        elevation="1"
        onClick={() => navigate("/astroline")}
      >
        Learn More
      </Button>
    </CardActions>
  </Card>
</Grid>
```

Or you can replace the `Grid` with a `Stack` component which will wrap your `Card`

`<Stack  alignItems="center">... Your <Card> content  ... </Stack`

Comment: I dont know why but it didnt work?? i looked at the codesandbox aswell and copied everthing new in there but it still wont work...

Comment: Please consider marking it as accepted answer for future users.

Comment: @MrBlubDev what is not working for you exactly so i can have a look? In the Codesandbox example the Card is centered. So what is not working?